# How to expire the browser session in case of user inactivity in java?

Tags: java, session, web-applications

i want to expire the my browser  session  in case of user inactivity for 1 minutes in my web application? I tried  doing two things :-

**Approach1:-**  put the below code in web.xml

```
<session-config>
  <session-timeout>1</session-timeout> 
</session-config>
```

**Approach2:-**

```
session.setMaxInactiveInterval(1*60);
```

Both the aproaches does not expire the session. I am ablke to continue even if user does not do the activity for 3 minutes?

**When it is not working:-** it does not work  when  when i go to login screen directly and do the login.

**when it works:-** Though same approach works when i integrate above web application to with one of mine different web application say webapp2. What happens in this case i provided a link on webapp2 which directly takes me to webapp1 without asking login credentials. Here log out works in case user does not do the activity for 1 minutes?

i am not getting why it is not working in first case when i do the log in manually though web.xml is same and class where i put  session.setMaxInactiveInterval(1*60) is executed in both the cases?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The session is timed out only when the server finds inactivity from the client side
for a period of defined in web.xml / session / session-time-out. You should test if it is working or not by sending a request from client and after it gets the response, just close the browser window. Send one more request after session timeout interval. Check if it is a new session (check sessionID). Further help ?`enter code here`  read below -

Well there is a thing called web application listener for java based web applications.
These listeners listens to requests, sessions and related things of the clients. For session timeout handling you can use session listeners. Step 1 - Modify web.xml to include a web application listener:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>some.package.name.MySessionListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

And, now create the above mentioned class in your source directory:

```
package some.package.name;

public class SessionListener implements javax.servlet.http.HttpSessionListener {

    public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent arg0) {
        //write your own code for when new session is created.
    }

    public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent arg0) {
        //Write your own c`enter code here`ode for when session is destroyed.
    }
}
```

Hope you find it useful. :)     .

Comment: hi sadsa,Thanks for reply. My application is alreading using listener which implements ServletContextListener. But my main question is Why it is working in one scenario not for other when i am directly doing login with credentials